# context menu with full calendar, passing data between calendar and context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I am using jquery context menu , with  Adam Shaw's full calendar (on event right click).
And it works pretty well, but, how do I pass data other than what appears on the event UI, on the eventClick to the context menu? I have tried to pass info through .targetdata but was not successful. Please help!

```
$('#calendarView').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        var originalClass = element[0].className;
        element[0].className = originalClass + ' hasmenu';
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        //need to pass calEvent.ID to context menu                   
    },
});

$('#calendarView').contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasmenu",
    preventContextMenuForPopup: true,
    preventSelect: true,
    menu: [{
        title: "Edit Booking",
        cmd: "Edit",
        action: function(event, ui) {}
    }, {
        title: "Delete Booking",
        cmd: "Delete",
        action: function(event, ui) {
            //need to pick up calEvent.ID here
        }
    }],
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // Logic for handing the selected option
    },
    beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
        ui.menu.zIndex($(event.target).zIndex() + 1);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did was:

1. in eventRender: function...  i would do

`element.attr('data-event-id', event.id);
element.addClass('context-class');`

then in a document ready function attached the context menu to all .context-class elements.

inside the context menu code, you get the element and can pull the 'data-' attributes out for what you need

Comment: Thank you!! worked like a charm. Though, I had to twist the code a little bit because, the calendar plugin and context menu picked up two different elements. So I finally ended up with this code in the context menu                                                                                                      menu: [{
      
        title: "Delete Booking",
        cmd: "Delete",
        action: function(event, ui) {
             var eventID = ui.target.closest('a').attr("data-event-id");
        }
    }],

Comment: Hi, could you do this also on resources? I need a context menu for resources, knowing that select does not exist for resources...

Comment: Hi, in fullcalendar 4.0, no support for element, so I added 'class' as the extendedProps for the event object, then added context menu based on this class name but unable to send the event id details when I click on context menu on that specific event as I can only get the event title(that is what is showing on the UI target), how to get the ID of that particular event as like the mentioned  above(element.attr('data-event-id', event.id);), please suggest.

Comment: Hi, I achieved through event render as : eventRender: function eventRender( info ) { info.el.setAttribute("idgiven",info.event.id); }

Answer (score 0):

Starting from *version 5* should be used [Event Render Hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) to assign some meta-info to markup.

```js
const idCustomAttributeName = 'data-event-id';

const calendar = new Calendar(element, {
  ..
  eventDidMount: info => {
    const id = info.event.id;
    $('.fc-event-main-frame', info.el).attr(idCustomAttributeName, id);
  }
};

$.contextMenu({
  selector: '.fc-event-main-frame',
  callback: (key, options) => {
    ..
    const eventId = options.$trigger.attr(idCustomAttributeName);
  }
});
```